# Android app terminate

Tags: android

I really need to be able to terminate the app on menu button click.
My menu works just fine, but when I try to terminate/kill the app, it just closes the current activity and opens the previous one.

- I need to be able to navigate back and forth between the activities in the app using the back button, or the designed by me navigation buttons
- In the menu, I added a button for exiting the app and inside the click event, I entered the code

  **android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())**
- However nothing happens, I mean it's the same. Behaves like Finish(). I need to finish all my activities when that button is clicked.
- I pretty much **hate the back button** when entering deep in an app, and navigating for a couple of minutes, then when you want to close the app... without clicking Home button, it takes you almost the same amount of time to go back through all the steps that you did before, in reverse... it's annoying to say the least.
- Plus, my app makes HTTP requests onCreate of almost every Activity, so my app will make double internet traffic when going "back". And "YES" my app needs to do this. I cannot cache my database locally and use it from here, because my app will be used by multiple users simultaneously and they need to see the updated data every time they enter an Activity
- **I do not want/need my app to remain open for future use**. My app will require a user+pass authentication and i need to provide the safety of being able to close it when user wants to log-off it, so he can leave his phone safely on the table when leaving for the toilet (it's just an example).
- I do not need a lecture about why Android wants me to not close my app... **I DO NOT CARE what Android would like me to do**. It's **what I would like to do, that is more important**. If my user leaves his phone unattended, anyone can just start the app and be logged in and see whatever information my app is storing, so NO, I do not want my app to linger on. I want it **STOPPED** when the user chooses to stop it.

So please tell me how to do it?
I tried adding in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

for every activity and then added this whenever I start an activity:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

nothing changed... when I click the exit button, current activity finishes and previous activity shows up. I hate this.
Please tell me how to do it.

There are plenty TaskManager applications out there that let you **finish other apps**, so there has to be a way to be able to **finish your own app...**

Thank you

Comment: You can scream/bold all the sentences you want about what how you don't care about certain things, but in the end you are trying to fabricate your own rules for the sake of "security". The best way would be to actually make your app behave as is expected. Don't make up your own 'rules' and then complain it's not as easy as it should be. If you want a user to be able to log out, why not add a "log-out" button? Or log-out after a timeout, on focus-loss (home-button pressed) etc? (so keep a 'state' instead of running/closed as your base)

Comment: The best idea is to use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity to start your next Activity. I mean if you are currently in Activity A and starting Activity B, then use startActivityForResult. Then when then Activity B is finish(). Then in  the onActivityResult method of Activity A you can pass a unique request code to identify that the Activity B has called finish() and wants the app to exit. Then you can call finish() method of Activity A.

Comment: @ArshadParwez No, that's not best idea. Best idea is to not force Activities to exit. And anyway `finish()` does not exit the Activity, it tells Android this Activity is no longer needed.

Comment: @m0skit0 : I have implemented the same thing which I commented above to exit from my app and its working fine. Moreover this.finish() is the proper way to end the Activity, it does not force the Activity to exit. Instead its System.exit(0) which forces the Activity to exit.

Comment: I did not say it will not work. I said it is not best idea. What I mean is `finish()` does not really exit the `Activity` right away. It is up to Android when to destroy your `Activity`, so the `Activity` instance might still exist even if you don't see it, and a potential attacker can exploit this to recover data from this instance. `System#exit` and `Activity#finish` do 2 totally different things: first one exits the JVM (which kills the process and thus exits the app), while the second one marks the Activity as not needed (which doesn't have to exit the process).

Comment: @Nanne -  I was not shouting :). I just wanted to underline the important parts of the text. I agree I can do it in another way, but that would be more complicated than a simple APP.KILL. Also rules are beautiful, but when put in practice they are not that good. I have friends that own Samsung Galaxy Ace and Sony Xperia something, phones who cannot start facebook app,  or other apps because the phones do not have enough available memory, or even slow down and become unresponsive when too many apps are running in the background. So the rules are nice but they only apply to the best hardware...

Comment: But that is just not true: when another app needs the memory, background apps will be closed, so something else must be going on.

Comment: So wanting to be able to close an app when you are sure you wont need it again soon, or when you want to be sure that no one else can access the app, should be allowed, without so much hassle. And without third party apps that kill processes for you. The fact that these kind of apps exist means that they they are needed, so users need to be able to close processes... why shouldn't it be allowed to do it from inside your app? Let's face it, not everybody has Galaxy S3 or S4 overloaded with memory and processor power.

Comment: Trust me... theory is good, but practice showed me different. I witnessed it on more than 2 phones. I also reset some devices to factory settings, but after a few days and apps installed, same behavior occur. Maybe 2.3.6 version is not that good with resource handling

Comment: Also @Nanne, there are moments when the question (here in SO) editor does not work as it should and does not format the code as code... that is when I bold sometimes... :(

Answer (score 2):

`System.exit` exit the JVM and effectively kills the VM process.

Some notes about your "supposed" needs to exit the app, which IMHO do not justify killing the app and give the user a much worse experience using your app and also affect other apps and the device running it as a whole.

> I pretty much hate the back button when entering deep in an app, and
>   navigating for a couple of minutes, then when you want to close the
>   app... without clicking Home button, it takes you almost the same
>   amount of time to go back through all the steps that you did before,
>   in reverse... it's annoying to say the least.

That's why it's called "Back" and not "Exit". You can say the same about "Back" button in browsers.

> Plus, my app makes HTTP requests onCreate of almost every Activity, so
>   my app will make double internet traffic when going "back"

I don't know why it will make double traffic when going back. You said it should refresh, so at back if you want to refresh, you need to make the HTTP query again. I don't see anything wrong with this.

> I do not want/need my app to remain open for future use. My app will
>   require a user+pass authentication and i need to provide the safety of
>   being able to close it when user wants to log-off it

You don't need to exit for this. You can just flag the user as not logged in when it navigates away from your app. This way you can ask the user + pass each time he comes back and keep the same Activity shown so he/she doesn't have to navigate to this Activity again.

> I do not need a lecture about why Android wants me to not close my
>   app... I DO NOT CARE what Android would like me to do.

Then your app will start slower each time you come back to it, consume more battery and so on. Android app development guidelines are not "just because". There's a strong reason you need to follow this guidelines: because that's how Android works.

Comment: 1. As far as I know about System.exit... it closes all Java Virtual Machine depending apps that are running at the time.. 2. I agree with you about the back button in browsers, but browsers allow you to close the TAB or even the browser, while Android does not. 3. OnStartIntent I make a HTTP POST to an external php that retrieves data used to populate spinners or listviews, so everytime I go to a new activity I make traffic, so I am trying to avoid unnecessary POSTS and GETS that are adding to the users phone-data bill.

Comment: 4. It would be a solution, but where do I access the event for when the app is "minimized" by Home or repeated back-buttons ?

Comment: 5. I understand why Android wants the apps to behave this way. But some apps might need this. My app is not going to be closed every time. There will still be Home and Back button functionality, But When the user **wants to close it** he should be able to do it without having to use a Task Killer app. Also many phones running Android have limited resources, fact that forces the user to kill manually apps that are running in order to be able to run other new apps. So, admirable Android logic, works great in a fantasy world, but the reality forces us to make compromises.

Comment: 1. In Android each app has its own JVM, so this is not a problem

Comment: 3. Then you can check if this has already been done and not do it again.

Comment: 4. [Activity#onUserLeaveHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29)

Comment: 5. I never meant you never need to close your app. I meant in most cases (99%) you don't have to. You can always have an exit button as some apps have and force exit the application (`System#exit`).

Answer (score 0):

don't do it , the OS tells us when the App should be termined. You can never close your application.

Comment: Of course you **can** close your application. The point is you **should not**.

Comment: I know I should not. But then TaskKiller apps should not exist or should be banned :) I want to give an extra option to my user. Besides hiding the app, I want to give him the ability to kill his app too. If taskKiller apps exist and have a reason to exist, so does my functionality.

Comment: @user1137313 You should track your backstack of your activies very carefully.

Comment: @user1137313 And System.exit or other functions bring nothing to achiv your point. If the OS or other Apps share resource with your app, your App or process of your App will be re-actived after your call these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

with

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

and try. It worked in my case...I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this in the exit button click event:

```
 System.exit(0);
```